# How the app can update automatically when there is a new message sent to the WebSocket using Jetpack Compose

Tags: websocket, android-jetpack-compose

I am doing a chat app and use websocket for send and receive message. I do not know how the app can automatically update the list of message when there is a new message sent (from user or user's friend).

This is my code. In this code, I use WebSocketService.getInstance().setCallback to check whether there is a new message sent to the server, then update the chatList. I do not know whether I put the WebSocketService.getInstance().setCallback here is right or wrong (whether it can update the list chatList).

```
@Composable
fun ChatScreen(
    navHostController: NavHostController
){
    var message by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val person = navHostController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<Room>("data") ?: Room()
    val user = navHostController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<User>("user") ?: User()
    val conversation = navHostController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<Conversation>("conversation") ?: Conversation()
    val roomId = navHostController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<Int>("roomId") ?: -1
    var chatList1 = conversation.rows ?: emptyList<Message>()

    var chatList by remember{mutableStateOf(listOf<Message>())}
    chatList = chatList + chatList1

    WebSocketService.getInstance().setCallback(object: WebSocketCallback {
        override fun onReceiveMessage(message: Message){
            chatList = chatList + listOf(message)

        }
    })
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.White)
    ){
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            inforBar (person, modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 30.dp, start = 10.dp, end = 20.dp), navHostController)
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(top = 15.dp, start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp, bottom = 20.dp)
                    .background(Color.White)


            ){
                LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(top = 10.dp, bottom = 75.dp),
                    reverseLayout = true
                ){
                    items(chatList, key = {it.id?:Int}){
                        chatRow(user, chat = it, person)
                    }
                }
                chatInput(roomId = roomId, message = message, modifier = Modifier.align(BottomCenter), modifierText = Modifier.align(
                    Center)){
                    message = it
                }


            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: it would be better to create a viewmodel and keep web socket stuff there, but still if u want to call it here, then I think u need to use side effect(try launchEffect) for this, because right now, u r creating instance on each recomposition